# Show flag drop down from /review page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

When you click the "flag for attention" link on the /review page it just produces "Post flagged for attention from /review", rather than something specific (like "not an answer"). Could we just show the usual flagging drop down rather than these shortcuts?

Comment: I know I have accidentally flagged a few answers because of this, when I had expected to see the lightbox popup first instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done, flagging dialog now matches the exact same dialog you have elsewhere.

Also I removed the total flags left number from the right column as it shows up in the flag dialog anyway.

I do not hide the posts after being flagged, the reason is that I wanted you to be able to track which posts you flagged (also it would require a fairly involved internal api change)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this, it's very confusing that the dialogue works differently depending on where in the interface you are. Also, the fact that the "flag this post"-link goes straight to flagging means that there is no wiggle room for miss-clicks, which in turn can lead to faulty flagging.

I just flagged an answer from the review page because I accidentally clicked "flag this post" rather than "show full answer", and since I cannot flag an answer twice there is no way for me to inform the moderator that the answer I flagged really shouldn't have been flagged at all. The usual flagging drop-down would have easily stopped that.

The flagging functionality should be the same regardless of where you're flagging a post from.